# Access Couchbase cluster from config file (sbt)

Tags: sbt, config, couchbase

I'm pretty new to Couchbase and am trying to access a cluster from my `config` file. I'm not 100% sure how to do this.

The general framework I have is:

```
couchbase {
  buckets = [{
    host= // string
    port= // string
   ...
  }]
  servers = [{
    uri= // node1
    uri= // node2
    uri= // node3
    ...
  }]
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? Or, am I totally missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The [couchbase-scala](https://github.com/ohze/couchbase-scala/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/sandinh/couchbase/CBCluster.scala) project may be a starting point for you.

It uses [typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) to define and load configuration information.

See [CBCluster.scala](https://github.com/ohze/couchbase-scala/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/sandinh/couchbase/CBCluster.scala) to see how the configuration is used to connect to a Couchcbase cluster.